# R move named column to the end of a data frame

Tags: r

I'm trying to move a column to the end of a data frame and I'm struggling

`output_index <- grep(output, names(df))
  df <- cbind(df[,-output_index], df[,output_index])`

This orders the data properly, however it converts the data to a matrix which doesn't work. How can I do this without losing the column names and keeping the data as a data frame.

Comment: Remove the commas in the data frame subsets i.e. `df[-output_index]` not `df[,-output_index]`

Comment: @RichardScriven - is that true though? `is.data.frame(cbind(iris[,-1], iris[,1]))` returns `TRUE` - you lose the name, yes, but it's still a `data.frame`

Comment: Who knows.  It's hard to tell without a reproducible example.  Maybe there were only two columns to begin with.  Then they would both be dropped to vectors before `cbind`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't need the , in front of the index:

`output_index <- grep(output, names(df))
  df <- cbind(df[-output_index], df[output_index])`

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(id=1:10, output=rnorm(10,1,1), input=rnorm(10,1,1))
output_index <- grep("output", names(df))
res.df <- cbind(df[,-output_index], df[,output_index])
```